# Perform jQuery operations on an HTML page that was retrieved via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

Let's say you're retrieving a complete HTML page using Ajax. You now have a page of HTML in a variable.

Assuming you need to find and extract some data from that page, how do you do it?

Traditionally I've done this using regular expressions, but I'm wondering if there's a way to perform jQuery operations on that retrieved source code instead. It would simplify things tremendously, as jQuery is built for parsing HTML DOM trees.

I'm thinking maybe appending the retrieved source to the current page DOM in hidden form...? Is there a better way?

Comment: Just use the jQuery constructor - `$()`. Pass the string of HTML page and it is traversable

Comment: @Ian: You should add this as an answer, cause it is the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

jQuerys parseHTML might be what you are looking for: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you well, you have the html code of the page loaded through ajax in a variable (let's call it data), and then you want to search through it using jquery operations.
You could create a container in your first html page, and then fill it with the content returned by Ajax. You can then handle it normally with jQuery
So:

```
  <body>
    <div id="first_page">
            <h3>First page</h3>
             <p>This the page that makes the Ajax call</p>
    </div>
    <div id="ajax_container"></div>
 </body>
```

Now, after you Ajax call, you fill the container with data

```
$("#container").html(data);
```

Then, you can use .find(), or simply write an appropriate jquery selector.

```
 var a = $("#container").find("#my_id").html; 
 var b = $("#container #my_id").html();
```

Now a and b should contain the content from the element with id my_id from the page loaded with Ajax

PS: I'm not sure if you *want* to append the data to you current page. You don't *have* to, if that's not what you are trying to achieve.